# Conflicting method names in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-template-engine

I am using Jenkins Templating Engine, and I created a few libraries that implement the `build` step, e.g. `cmake` library.

The problem is, that down the flow I want to call the [Build a job](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/#build-build-a-job) step contributed by the Pipeline plugin suite, and once I try to call it:

```
build job: "Job_Name", parameters: "..."
```

I get an error from JTE because it tries to call my `cmake::build` step. Is there a way to call the Pipeline's build step explicitly?

Comment: couldn't just rename the cmake step to something different (eg `cmakeBuild`)?

Answer (score 1):

I think this could help:

```
'org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.BuildTriggerStep'(job: "job name")
```

What this does is calling directly the `BuildTriggerStep`, which is the class under the package `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build` and will do exactly the same as the `build` step.

I got that from [The source code of the build step plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-build-step-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/BuildTriggerStep.java)